# KDE4 separate taskbar buttons per desktops

Tags: kde, kde-4

I'm using KDE4 with 4 workspaces (or virtual desktops), and I would like only the windows of only the current workspace to show up on the taskbar. How can I do that?

Edit: OpenSUSE 11.2 here. There's no "task manager settings" in the right click menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it according to a comment by user moduc from digg:

> To go to the task manager settings is not straight forward, or would I say stupid design at best. First, I have to right click on the task manager, then Click on Panel Settings. Next, I right click on one of the icons of an app or window, and click on Task manager settings.

This exactly worked.

Comment: In my kde 4.3 I just right click on the panel, select task manager settings and that's it.

Answer (score 12):

Right click on Panel, Task Manager settings (in my config Alt + D, S) - and there you go:

- Show tasks from current desktop

in **Filters** section. Using latest Kubuntu Karmic here.

Answer (score 1):

I had to right-click in a part of the task manager area that wasn't showing a task.  Once the task manager area is full, there seems to be noplace where the task manager settings can be invoked.  Seems like a bug to me.